# How to take today's date and output it as mmddyy?

Tags: excel, vba

As the title asks, I want to format today's date into mmddyy ina variable for a macro to make saving a file easier. So since today's date is August 14, 2015 I want the variable to read 081415.

Comment: =TEXT(Date(),"mmddyy") perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm, well when I try that it doesn't know what TEXT() is and give me a compilation error there

Comment: Oh didn't realize text() isn't built into vba. Add worksheetfunction. infron of it so it reads worksheetfunction.text(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA equivalent is format. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx).

```
=Format(Date,"mmddyy")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider being vary careful when handling dates depending on your location.

A constant problem I had in the UK was excel trying to as usual help and insisting on interpreting some dates as US.
For example
1st August 2015 you would expect `010815` in the UK.
However excel would regularly give `080115` formatting as though it was US.

To be completely sure of the correct date, you should be explicit with the date eg.

```
format(dateserial(year(now()),month(now()),day(now())),"mmddyy")
```

Comment: Definitely good advice for dates in general, but for what the OP is asking, there should be no ambiguity in code such as this: `format(date(),"mmddyy")`
Also, I think you mean "you should be *explicit* with the date." Compare the first definitions of [explicit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/explicit) vs. [implicit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/implicit)